# ZF2 - Get current URL in Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

This seems like it should be a simple task. I need the current URL from a function within the Controller. This function can be called from multiple actions, and the end goal is to set a form's action attribute. (Side note: It appears IE does not send an ajax request if the URL starts with '#').

I feel like my google-fu is off today because I could not find a good way to do this Zend Framework 2. I have this line currently, but it feels very bulky:

```
 $this->url()->fromRoute(
    $this->getServiceLocator()
    ->get('Application')
    ->getMvcEvent()
    ->getRouteMatch()
    ->getMatchedRouteName()
  );
```

Comment: "end goal is to set a form's action attribute" I would use a relative URL by omitting the first argument of the url view helper. e.g `$this->url();` this would return the last matched *route* rather than the complete url (which appears to be what you want).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't you just get the URI from the request object:

$this->getRequest()->getUriString()

Provided your controller extends `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController`.

Note: This would output the entire URL, like so:

```
 http://example.com/en/path/subpath/finalpath?test=example
```

Answer (score 5):

If your request route is like this:

```
http://example.com/en/path/subpath/finalpath?test=example
```

And You want only this:

```
/en/path/subpath/finalpath?test=example
```

You can simply do : `$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri()`

> To specify my Request object is an instance of
>
> `\ZF\ContentNegotiation\Request`